# Home Page Only Footer

Tags: wordpress, footer

I have a blog, http://sweatingthebigstuff.com and I would like to add an extra line in the footer which will display only from the homepage. I found this code, but it is not working for me. Do I have the wrong syntax or is there something else I can try to get this to work?

```
<?php if ( is_home() ) { ?>
text
<?php } ?>
```

Here is where footer.php is called

```
<?php include (TEMPLATEPATH . '/sidebar1.php'); ?>

<div class="cleared"></div>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

And here is the footer code:

text 2

Contact | Disclaimer | Privacy Statement
Copyright © 2009-2010 Sweating The Big Stuff. All Rights Reserved.

and then some sitemeter crap.

Answer (score 2):

`is_home()` sets a global var that doesn't seem to reset itself or re-evaluate, wp kinda strange.

Try putting `wp_reset_query()` at the <s>end</s> start of your if statement code

Actually, it'll be better to call it before as we can ensure the queries are reset

```
<?php wp_reset_query();
if ( is_home() ) { ?>
text
<?php }  ?>
```

Now that the php is working, ideally you'd want the code above. 
 

    
    <s>text</s>

I just did a view source and I can plainly see the php code, which shouldn't be visible since it is meant to be parsed server side. The following shouldn't be there in the view source.... wrong file being edited?

```
<p>
<?php if ( is_home() ) { ?> 
text 
<?php } ?>
<wp_reset_query()>
<br />
<br />
```

The footer.php file should be located in wp-content/themes/nameofyourtheme folder

Comment: after you've called is_home() to ensure the next time it's called, the query is reset. Or you could put it before it. See if it works.

Comment: EDIT: I just had a quick look at your html, the wp_reset_query() needs to be put inside <?php ?> tags - Currently, it's showing up as html which isn't correct.

hmm.... the only other thing I can think of is for you to try is_front_page() instead of is_home(), if that doesn't work, i'm outta ideas...

Comment: I know literally 0 php. Can you tell me how to put the wp_reset_query() inside <?php ?> tags?

Comment: See my edit, wp_reset_query() is a php function call, so whenever you want to use php functions, just put a <?php functionhere ?> around the function if you're not sure.

Comment: Neither of those are working for me. Same issue, it appears on all pages.

Comment: You able to post you footer.php code? I see an extra wp_reset_query in the html now >.>

Comment: I had it for a minute then removed it when I noticed. I just posted everything above.

Comment: hang on, here's your problem. the php isn't getting parsed. are you sure you're editing footer.php, not footer.html?

Comment: ah you're right. I was doing it from my dashboard but I need to edit that file. Does it matter where in that code I place it?

Comment: well, for one it has to be within the footer.php file and where you put the code within that file will affect where it displays... Try not to use the dashboard editor, it's not reliable as it does html formatting to escape strings and what not which can be a problem. You should really download the file and edit using notepad before reuploading or if your cpanel file manager has a text editor, that'll suffice too.

Comment: The frontpage version worked, but it displays on page2, page3, etc. It doesn't appear on archive pages or on individual posts. What's up with that?

Comment: hmm... the behaviour is a bit off. if you check http://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags you'll see the functionality. ideally you'd want to use is_home() if that works. Try the is_home() code with the wp_reset_query() before it. Remember to put the code in the proper file.

Answer (score 1):

`is_home()` is a method that should return true or false. You need to implement this method somewhere. If blogspot doesn't implement this method for you, you need to do it yourself. For your website I think this function would do what you want:

```
<?php
function is_home(){
    $r = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    return $r == '/' || $r == '' || $r == '/index.php';
}

if(is_home()) {
?>
text
<?php } ?>
```

And where you want the footer, put:

```
<?php include 'footer.php'; ?>
```

instead of the line:

```
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

I believe your problem is that get_footer() is reading the footer as text, so it isn't executing the PHP beforehand. If you do it this way you can add as much PHP in the header as you want.

Comment: There is a flaw in your system somewhere because I see your php code when I look at your document source. Either you don't have the right extension on your file, or you aren't doing something right because the php code isn't being executed.

Comment: The file must be right because the text displays, but it displays everywhere.

Comment: No, that is false. The text is being displayed because the browser just ignores invalid tags. As a test try putting, "<gibberish>hello, world</gibberish>". "hello, world" will still be displayed even though it is invalid. If you go to your page and view source, you will see that your PHP isn't being executed, it is just being outputted like HTML. And I just tested your page by copying everything, and alas, it only displays "text" when on the home page.

Comment: I see what you were saying. I thought you were saying it doesn't call footer.php at all.

Comment: On my site, it only displays 'text' but it does so on every page, so what do you think the solution is?

Comment: Can you update your question with the code where you are including footer.php?

Comment: Samuel: do you know that `is_home()` is a wordpress conditional tag?  there's no need to define it as your own function to use it.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with your syntax, and when I view your page source, I see " text "

What is the file extension of your footer page?  if it is "footer.php" then I shouldn't see the opening and closing terms for php ().  php won't run unless the file extension is ".php"

as to a previous answer:

`<?php wp_reset_query();?>` should go BEFORE `<?php if(is_home()){?>text<?php } ?>` in this scenario.  is_home() depends on a loop being present on the page.  Maybe somewhere you used a custom query, or one of your plugins used a custom query that upset the default query vars.  Like I said, use the reset statement before your if statement.

Comment: Thanks, but that still doesn't fix the problem. It's still showing up on every page.

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify the code to include a check for `is_front_page()` like so:

```
<?php
    $ishomepage = ( is_home() || is_front_page() );
    switch( $ishomepage )
    {
        case true :
            echo 'Your homepage-only snippet of text goes here';
            break;

        case false :
        default :
            // Do nothing... or do something else...
            break;
    }

?>
```

Reference: [WordPress Codex: is_front_page()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_front_page)

Default WP installations don't have a homepage defined, it uses your index.php and checks for other templates like a `home.php` template as a starting point (`home.php` only if your theme has it.) Here's a diagram from their online docs that shows how their hierarchy works: [WordPress Template Hierarchy](http://codex.wordpress.org/images/1/18/Template_Hierarchy.png).

> By default, WordPress shows your most recent posts on the front page
>   of your site. But many WordPress users want to have a static front
>   page or splash page as the front page instead. This "static front
>   page" look is common for those who wish to not have a "blog" look to
>   their site, giving it a more CMS (content management system) feel.

If you want to know how to set a static homepage, read this article and follow the instructions: [Creating a Static Frontpage](http://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_a_Static_Front_Page). When you set a static front page, `is_home()` will work as expected.